# std::regex issue with gcc 5.1

Tags: regex, c++11, gcc

I have the following regex expression:

(.*)[[:space:]]+(.+)[[:space:]]+(Error|Information|Trace)([[:space:]]+[1234567890]+)?([[:space:]]+[ndmptl]{1,6})?

When I try to initialize an std::regex variable with that expression, it intermittently crashes.

Here is some test code:

```
std::string matchRegex ("(.*)[[:space:]]+(.+)[[:space:]]+(Error|Information|Trace)([[:space:]]+[1234567890]+)?([[:space:]]+[ndmptl]{1,6})?");

std::regex rm (matchRegex); // intermittently crashes on this line
```

I am using gcc 5.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.  In particular, I am using the TDM gcc 64 MinGW flavor of gcc.

The crash only happens when I generate 32-bit code (via the gcc flag -m32).

64-bit code always works.

Is there a bug in the std::regex implementation that might be causing this?

I checked my regex with several online regex checkers and it passed 100% of the time.

Comment: do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: IMHO, I have given everything needed in those 2 lines of code.  It randomly crashes when it tries to create the std::regex local variable with the specified regex string.  This only happens on 32-bit code.

Comment: No, you have not given everything needed. Everything needed is a buildable program that reproduces the problem. If you have a short program that crashes, post the entire program, not the two lines you think are the problem. People around here will want to test your claim. No one should be required to reconstruct the entire program out of a fragment, however trivial this task is.